# Sticky Menu - Hides on some pages but not others

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hubspot

The sticky menu on our site (http://462184.hs-sites.com/) is experiencing issues on some pages and not others.

For example the homepage, if you scroll half way down the page and try to use the menu, it hides momentarily. On the other hand we don't get this issue when on another page such as (http://462184.hs-sites.com/bookkeeping-plans).

Therefore I can only imagine it is some type of element on those pages conflicting?

Your support is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Try removing overflow hidden from this element:

```
.header-container {
  /* overflow: hidden; */
}
```

Just remove the line, or you can replace it with `overflow:initial` or `overflow:auto;`

Comment: Hi @lharby thanks for you help - It fixes the problem however the header then spills over into the rest of the page.

Comment: It looked OK to me when I tested it in the browser. The other option might be to fix the height. Do you mean you cannot separate the header view from the page when the page is the same blue as the header?